# Better to make new wp_query or only modify main query each time?

Tags: wp-query

I have a theme where I need multiple queries for each column. Is it better to modify the main query with pre_get_post and reset the loop or create a new query for each of my columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are making some confusion between main query and secondary queries in Wordpress. Maybe read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110845/what-exactly-defines-a-main-loop-and-a-secondary-loop/110861#110861) can help you to better understand.

In short when you visit an url of your site, that url make wordpress fires a query on db: this is **the** main query.

Thanks to the action `pre_get_post` you can modify the main query, e.g. adding, removing or edit query vars **before** the query is runned on db.

But once the query fired, the only chance to recreate a query that you can call *'main'* <sup>**1**</sup> (even if is not triggered by url)  is use `query_posts`, but this practice is **highly** not recommended.

So if your question is: *"Should I use new `WP_Query` instances for multiple queries or should I use multiple `query_posts` calls?"*

The answer is, surely, new `WP_Query` instances.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> You can call 'main' the query runned by `query_posts`, because the main query, is characterized from 2 aspects (besides the fact that *normally* is triggered by the url):

1. It's an object (an instance of `WP_Query` more precisely) named `$wp_query` in the global scope. (You can access to it using `global $wp_query;`)
2. You can cycle the posts handled by this query using [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Once the query you obtain using `query_posts` have both these characteristics, it *is* fledged the main query, even if is not triggered by url.

Comment: Thank you, the link and this answer are very useful! But I think I don't understand something. There can be multiple queries considered as a main query? Because if I do a secondary query, it is an instance of WP_Query and I can cycle the posts with this query, so it has the same characteristics of a main query?

Comment: @Maxwell you can loop the secondary query, but you have to use `while($myquery->have_posts())` and not only `while (have_posts())`, see the difference? And then, the main query is accessible everywhere, using `global $wp_query;` the secondary query not, the are accessible via the variable that you assign to it, e.g. `$my_query`: if you assign the name `$wp_query` and put it in the global scope, you will breack a lot of things...