# how to limit query_post to first page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination, query

I have a custom post type called listings with different taxanomies, I am using this query to display first only my post that have the type taxonomy featured. This is the code that does that :

```
<?php
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'listings','type' => 'featured' ) );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>


<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php
```

I want this query to limit it self to the first page in wich i have 10 post

Answer (score 0):

If your question is:

> I want this query to limit it self to the first page in wich i have 10 post

I think adding a `'posts_per_page' => 10` array parameter will do the thing for you:

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'listings','type' => 'featured','posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
```

But above all, I'd like to recommend you to use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead, because of a [Great cause](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). And moreover it will give you much ease with a lot of query arguments. And you [can use](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/multiple-queries-on-home-page-page-load-site-speed-issue) a lot of them even in a single page, and with no danger.