# putting wp_query data into html table

Tags: table

I needed to display some data in a simple html table so I started with very basics of table. As shown in the code, the data needed was a list of custom-field-values of a meta_key *submitdate*, from across all the posts, under a specific tag **"female"**. I wrote the following code and everything worked perfectly till the first `WP_Query`.

UPDATE : Current code as suggested by @islam.

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>NO.</th>
<th>FEMALE DATA</th>
<th>MALE DATA</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<?php
$fmargs = array ( 'tag' => 'female', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$female_query = new WP_Query( $fmargs );
while ( $female_query -> have_posts() ):
$female_query -> the_post(); ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'submitdate', true); ?>
</td>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the first query
?>


<?php
$margs = array ( 'tag' => 'male', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$male_query = new WP_Query( $margs );
while ( $male_query -> have_posts() ):
$male_query -> the_post(); ?>
<td>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'submitdate', true);?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the second query
?>



</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I needed a list of data filled in similar way into second column in the same table for another tag "male". When I tried a second similar `WP_Query`, it returns the data but it either fills up into the wrong row or a single cell or completely breaks out of table. as I tried endless varieties of `<tr> and <td>` . So, I am **unable to get the data listed into the second column** exactly as the first column.

After writing so far I just realized that this question could be categorized as non-wordpress issue, so if you feel I should definitely ask it somewhere, Please let me know, else a little helping hand is always appreciated. Here is a screenshot of the current result. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is happening with your code:

1. `query_posts` uses the `global` variable `wp_query`. It always
   overwrites that variable, which is why you [**should not use
   `query_posts`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) pretty much ever.
2. Your first `query_posts` clobbers the original `$wp_query` data.
3. You start the Loop
4. The first thing you do in that loop is *reset `$wp_query`* to the
   original query. Now the `$wp_query` `global` has different data that
   it had when the loop started.
5. You then clobber `$wp_query` yet again
6. And start a new loop
7. And then reset the query again.

In other words, your data is overwritten and out of sync is several different ways. The fix is to **not use `query_posts`**. Use a new `WP_Query` object instead.

```
 $outer = new WP_Query( array ( 'tag' => 'female', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
 if ($outer->have_posts()) {
   while ( $outer->have_posts() ) {
     $outer->the_post();
     // ...
```

The rest of your problem is really a PHP/HTML one, but here is a rough outline. What you need to do is iterate over both arrays at once.

```
$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$female_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$male_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = max($female_query->found_posts,$male_query->found_posts);
var_dump($count);

echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
      echo $i;
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<td>';
      if (isset($female_query->posts[$i])) {
        echo $female_query->posts[$i]->post_title;
      }
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<td>';
      if (isset($male_query->posts[$i])) {
        echo $male_query->posts[$i]->post_title;
      }
    echo '<td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

`$post` isn't set in my code. This is a non-standard Loop because you need data from two queries at once. To get the meta data use `$female_query->posts[$i]->ID` instead of `$post->ID` or pass it through `setup_postdata`-- `setup_postdata($female_query->posts[$i])`-- though that is probably overkill for this circumstance.

Comment: hope the updated code in accordance to your suggestion.

Comment: That is the idea, but you have now edited the question such that it is not the same question anymore.

Comment: I will edit the question/answer in order to make sense. Problem is still I cant get the data (list) of second query into the second column properly as it does on first column. Any ideas if I am placing the `<td> or <tr>` wrong, or is it not possible ?

Comment: ,new code is flawless and it inserts post titles to table cells now, instead can it be made to return the values of the custom field please. I tried `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'submitdate', true)` and it didnot work.

Comment: @gurung : see the edit

Comment: thanks, everything is perfect now. If you can point me to where can I learn more or find examples about these kind of non-standard loops as I am digging [here](codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) right now.

Comment: @gurung : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all DO NOT use `query_posts()`, it will modify your original loop; use `WP_Query()` instead ([Why?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)). And you can call them as of your need ([See here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/multiple-queries-on-home-page-page-load-site-speed-issue)).

```
<?php //Female Query ?>
<?php
$fmargs = array ( 'tag' => 'female', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$female_query = new WP_Query( $fmargs );
while ( $female_query -> have_posts() ):
$female_query -> the_post();
   echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'submitdate', true);
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the first query
?>
```

And

```
<?php //Male Query ?>
<?php
$margs = array ( 'tag' => 'male', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$male_query = new WP_Query( $margs );
while ( $male_query -> have_posts() ):
$male_query -> the_post();
   echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'submitdate', true);
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the second query
?>
```

Comment: thnks, code updated, the table issue persists though.